# How to customize spacing for footnotes?

Tags: spacing, footnotes

Currently I have:

```
in text: abc 1
at the bottom: 1abc
```

what I want is:

```
in text: abc1 (removed space)
at the bottom: 1 abc (added space)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can insert `\unskip` before `\footnote` and also a `\space` after `\@makefnmark` within `\@makefntext` (when the mark is set as part of the footnote text):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[paper=a6paper]{geometry}% Just for this example
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% Remove space before \footnote
\let\oldfootnote\footnote
\renewcommand{\footnote}{\unskip\oldfootnote}

% Insert space after mark in footnote text
\makeatletter
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\@makefntext}{\@makefnmark}{\@makefnmark\space}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\vspace*{\fill}% Just for this example

In the text: abc \footnote{abc}

\end{document}
```